# Организация справочников

Tags: структуры-данных, связывание-данных, php, sql

Здравствуйте!
Есть формы ввода данных, которые формируются динамически. Например, нужно в форме создать поля с названием, датой и выбрать сотрудника из списка. Все данные об этих полях хранятся в БД в таблице fields. Каждое fields связано через field_form с определённой формой (таблица form). Для такой формы мы по form.id берём все связанные с ней поля. С полем name (название) и date (дата) всё понятно - они будут input type="text" и в скрипте сформировать текстовое поле довольно просто. Но что делать со списком сотрудников (select)? Как формировать этот динамический список?

Сейчас в поле с описание поля в форме добавлен ещё 2 столбца - is_list и list_name. В старой разработке эти поля и описывали из какой таблицы БД брать информацию для этого выпадающего списка и были написаны соответствующие скрипты. Но я понимаю, что тут можно (и, наверное, даже нужно по-другому). Подскажите, пожалуйста, решали ли вы подобные задачи и как вы их решили?

update 1.
приведу простой пример:
сотруднику необходимо добавить информацию о том, какую грамоту он получил на конференции. Для этого он должен заполнить поля:

1. Название
2. Дата её проведения
3. Название награды
4. Место проведения

сотруднику необходимо добавить информацию о том, на какую награду получил его подчинённый:

1. Название (награды)
2. Дата проведения
3. Кто наградил
4. Сотрудник (выбор из списка)

В fields имеем:

id | value         | description

1 | name          | Название

2 | event_date    | Дата проведения

3 | award_name    | Название награды

4 | venue         | Место проведения

5 | date_of_award | Дата награждения

6 | presented_by  | Кто наградил

7 | person        | Сотрудник (!!! как раз тот самый список !!!)

в forms имеем:

id | value              | description

1 | awards             | Награды

2 | subordinate_awards | Награды подчинённых

в связующей таблице имеем:

form_id | field_id

1    |    1

1    |    2

1    |    3

1    |    4

2    |    3

2    |    2

2    |    6

2    |    7

При выводе нужно учитывать какого типа поле и давать пользователю input type="text", textarea или select на основании того, какое поле. С текстовыми полями проблем нет, а вот где и как указать, что полю "person" нужно "посмотреть" в список сотрудников и взять оттуда id сотрудника?!

Comment: Не понял следующее:

1) "Есть формы ввода данных, которые формируются динамически"

2) "Каждое fields связано через field_form с определённой формой (таблица form). Для такой формы мы по form.id берём все связанные с ней поля."

Так формы генерируются автоматически или они предопределены, а автоматически генерируется данные этой формы?

Если (1) - зачем связывать эти поля с формой?

Если (2) - то что используете? Шаблонизатор или сами выводите? Шаблонизаторы имеют встроенные средства вывода массивов. Если выводите сами - то просто foreach ... echo `структура select` ...

Comment: (1) для разных форм может использоваться одно и тоже поле, с одинаковыми правилами заполнения
(2) данные отправляются в шаблон, а в шаблоне формируется уже select.

Comment: А вы что используете? В Zend можно создать свой валидатор и применять его к различным элементам формы (это про "правила заполнения"). Или вы не про то?

И зачем формы хранить в БД? Оформление (css и расположение элементов) тоже через БД задается?

Ничего непонимаю (c) Шеф (Колобки)

Comment: И еще: есть две таблицы товаров: игрушки и фильмы. В форме у обоих есть имя.

Вы что будете делать? Два имени? Или одно "Наименование? Допустим одно имя.

Смотрите игрушки. Не понравилось, захотели назвать "Название игрушки".

И что теперь? В форме фильмов тоже будет "Название игрушки"?

Т.е. все равно создадите два имени. И для каждого из них будут применяться одни и те же правила.

Че-то мне кажется, что не тем путем вы пошли... Хотели одно (одно поле - одно правило заполнения), а получили другое (одно правило - куча имен)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На мой взгляд, у вас уже хорошо всё сделано. Осталось только выбрать и вывести данные. Когда элемент формы имеет аттрибут is_list (я бы назвал его selectable), делать выборку определённой колонки из определённой таблицы.

Если у вас есть возможность создавать **представления**, можно пойти иным путём. В таблицу `fields` *добавить колонку `view`*, в которой указывать имя представления, но только для тех полей, где требуется выборка, у остальных -- её значения будут `null`. В коде на PHP вам потребуется смотреть в колонку `view` и, если она не пустая, делать выборку из указанного в ней представления, иначе -- делать всё как у вас сейчас.

Само представление вы уже можете писать как вам угодно и данные брать откуда угодно. Лучше, конечно, чтобы каждое такое представление возвращало одну колонку (и ID для связи, конечно) -- эту колонку вы и будете помещать в качестве `select` на HTML-форму, а ID использовать при INSERT/UPDATE. Но плюс такого метода очевиден -- вам не потребуется менять ничего, кроме текста представления в будущем.

Comment: насчёт is_list / selectable: у меня есть ещё в field тип поля, который отображать пользователю. С отображением я сам разберусь. Меня смущает именно хранение данных, т.е. эти 1-2 колонки в fields. Не хочется изобретать велосипед. Может уже есть готовые какие-то проекты?

Comment: @kemerov4anin, ну тем более. В это имеющееся поле указываете "view" и используете колонку `view`. Это очень простой с точки зрения реализации способ. Не думаю, что для этого есть решение на все случаи жизни, тем более в виде "проекта".